# How to force rights elevation for WiX setupbld.exe

Tags: installation, wix, uac

I have created an MSI file and then setup.exe with setupbld.exe. I want to have this shield on the setup.exe icon, so when user try to run this installer, the user will immediately get this screen with [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (UAC) elevation. What should I do?

Currently I generate setup.exe with following cmd line:

```
setupbld.exe -out c:\Setup.exe -mpsu c:\outTEst\a.msi -setup setup.exe -title "setup"
```

Now users have to click on setup.exe and choose *Run as Administrator* in order to install my application.

Comment: I think that I know what should I do. I should use setupbld.exe to pack and them mt.exe with correct manifest file that force UAC elevation on setup.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the manifest in your resulting Setup.exe and change its `requestedExecutionLevel` attribute to `requireAdministrator`.

Yet, as Bob said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330533/how-to-force-rights-elevation-for-wix-setupbld-exe/5330800#5330800), you should better use [**Deferred Execution** Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368268%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with `NoImpersonate` bit set. Deferred custom actions have access only to a limited number of properties, see [Obtaining Context Information for Deferred Execution Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Also take a look at [UAC in MSI Notes: The NoImpersonate Bit Mistake](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/23/768248.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Setupbld.exe doesn't support marking for asAdministrator elevation. If your .msi can only run with "early" elevation, you have a bug in your .msi. Usually it's custom actions that need to be run in deferred context without impersonation.

Comment: Msi can run without evaluation howerver I have custom action and this action need administrator rights. What should I do is there any open source easy in use command line tool ?

Comment: To run a custom action with full privileges you can mark it as deferred with no impersonation.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/06/

This blog does pretty much exactly what you are talking about if I understand correctly. I'm using to give my msi Admin so that my custom actions function correctly. However I'm also writing and reading to the registry, and for some reason reading from the registry isn't working. The log file says that the AppSearches are returning signature 3, which I believe means access denied. I am still working out why this is happening.

Best.

Edit: I believe my registry issues are not related to my admin privileges, I know that my setup is giving me elevated privileges, so ignore the comment about registry issues.

Comment: Usually when I have issues with the registry I end up realizing that version of my application (x64 / x86) is causing the issue.

Comment: http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/06/ does not appear to be available (no response from the web server; it times out).